# Reference for Grothendieck's duality and Cousin, Dualizing and Residual complexes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories

I am a graduate student currently reading Hartshorne's Residues and Duality. In order to reach the construction of the right adjoint $f^!$ of $Rf_*$ for some special types of maps of locally noetherian schemes, he introduces the notion of cousin, dualizing and residual complexes. His presentation is quite crisp and nice but in order to get a first hand experience with these complexes one needs some examples which unfortunately are missing in his text.

So I am looking for a reference in which these notions are done in way that they are somewhat more informative for a beginner in the subject.

Comment: One famous use of Cousin complexes is Kempf's interpretation of the BGG resolution. I'm not sure there's a map $f$ involved there. "The Grothendieck-Cousin complex of an induced representation", Advances in Mathematics 09/1978; 29(3):310-396.

Comment: From MathSciNet you can get to Thomas LaFramboise's thesis "The Grothendieck-Cousin complex on $G/B\times G/B$" which I imagine spells these notions out more slowly, and anyway provides another example.